# Microsoft Designer mouse can't pair on Lenovo, Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, wireless-mouse

I've tried it all, I purchased a  **Microsoft Designer Bluetooth® Mouse,** but unable to pair it with my Lenovo Thinkpad Edge e520.

Tried to update system  with [this](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds028704), but installation process is stopped as current driver is up-to-date, as also tried [troubleshooting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811805) without success. Bought mouse yesterday.

Comment: Something I'd check is if the laptop supports BT at all. Not all do.

Comment: what is BT ? bluetooth ? if so yes of course